# how to genete a grammar in antlr with null is a terminating condoition?

Tags: java, antlr

```
identifier 
    : 'int' (ID|ID '=' INT) (','ID|','ID '=' INT)*';' '\n' identifier 
    | 'float' (ID|ID '=' FLOAT) (','ID|','ID '=' FLOAT)*';' '\n' identifier
    | 'char' (ID|ID '=' CHAR) (','ID|','ID '=' CHAR)*';' '\n' identifier
    | 'string' (ID|ID '=' STRING) (','ID|','ID '=' STRING)*';' '\n' identifier  
    ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;
STRING
    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

CHAR:  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\''|'\\') ) '\''
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

i return this code in antlr but it is not terminate the identifier
how to solve this?

Comment: your grammar rule for the identifier is not terminating. add | '\r' ? '\n'; to that

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar rule for the identifier is not terminating. add `| '\r' ? '\n'` to that rule

e.g

```
identifier 
    : 'int' (ID|ID '=' INT) (','ID|','ID '=' INT)*';' '\n' identifier 
    | 'float' (ID|ID '=' FLOAT) (','ID|','ID '=' FLOAT)*';' '\n' identifier
    | 'char' (ID|ID '=' CHAR) (','ID|','ID '=' CHAR)*';' '\n' identifier
    | 'string' (ID|ID '=' STRING) (','ID|','ID '=' STRING)*';' '\n' identifier  
    | '\r\n';
    ;
```

or you can try

```
identifier 
    : 'int' (ID|ID '=' INT) (','ID|','ID '=' INT)*';' '\n' identifier 
    | 'float' (ID|ID '=' FLOAT) (','ID|','ID '=' FLOAT)*';' '\n' identifier
    | 'char' (ID|ID '=' CHAR) (','ID|','ID '=' CHAR)*';' '\n' identifier
    | 'string' (ID|ID '=' STRING) (','ID|','ID '=' STRING)*';' '\n' identifier  
    | EOF
    ;
```

Comment: but the identifier is recursive so it can not end....it is infinite how to solve...